# How to get Fields of a declared object type?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class like this:

```
Class Example {
    public static final Date d1;
    public static final String s1;
    public static final Date d2;
    public static final Date d3;
}
```

Now, how can I get list of Fields with `Date` type ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with this question. Perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should help you get started.

```
Field[] fields = Example.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    if (field.getClass() == Date.class) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: @NaveenRamawat I have changed my post. But it was only a hint for Op starting with the reflection.

Comment: `f[0].getClass()` will return java.reflect.Field.

Comment: Why use a for:next loop on the field array and then do indexed access of the array from within the loop?

Comment: @BrettOkken [f.getclass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) returns a Class object. The other comment you are right. I have changed it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get all of the fields and then check the type.

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields%28%29)

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to have a look at the [Reflections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html). Especially the "Members" part.

Effectively you will have to acquire all the fields for the class and then check if they are `Date`s.